# Python Programming encoding numbers to letters

Tags: python

I am trying to create a code that will make 00 = a 01 = b and so on,                         For example, str2numsp('I like Python.') should return string 
'3452110810045241241907141353'.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, what have you tried?

Comment: You can use a combination of translate and hex encoding to do this very efficiently

Comment: Quick! Post what you have tried before the question is closed.

Comment: This is what I had tried. I knew what functions I needed, but I just wasn't sure on how to assign the numbers to the letters.                                             def str2numsp(x):

    char = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase

    num = string.digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do they have to be in order starting at `0` or do you just want to use whatever number? You can use the unicode value of each character like so:

> ord("a") --> 97, ord("b) --> 98.. etc

Then you can say

```
myString = "I like Python"
```

And use a list comprehension

```
[ord(i) for i in myString]
```

Which outputs

```
[73, 32, 108, 105, 107, 101, 32, 80, 121, 116, 104, 111, 110]
```

Then concatenate them as strings

```
"".join([str(ord(i)) for i in myString])
```

Returns the final output

```
'73321081051071013280121116104111110'
```

If you want `'a'` to start at zero, you could always subtract 97 (which is 'a') from each `ord()` but you have to be careful about special characters (spaces, punctuation, etc).

Comment: It has to be in the specific order 00 = a 01 = b but it also has to include a number assigned for capital numbers, thank you. I do have clarification now from you all!

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + " ."
encode = {ch:"{:02d}".format(i) for i,ch in enumerate(chars)}

def str2numsp(s):
    return "".join(encode[ch] for ch in s)
```

which works like

```
>>> str2numsp("I like Python.")
'3452110810045241241907141353'
```